# Why is Finder hanging/beachballing after a Quick Look window is closed?

Tags: macos, finder

I select a file, hit Space for Quick Look, and then hit Space again to hide the window. Finder hangs and in some cases beachballs for a while before becoming responsive again.

Other notes:

- It gets worse over time. If I restart Finder the hang time is nonexistant. The more I use QuickLook, the slower it is. The hang is ~3 seconds after using (opening and closing) QuickLook 10 times. It only gets worse from there.
- Actually showing the file is always instantaneous in all cases
- Both /Library/QuickLook and ~/Library/QuickLook are empty.
- This is a Mid 2012 MacBook Air running 10.8.2 with all the software updates.
- Restarting the entire machine doesn't help any more than restarting Finder.
- **Update:** Other users on this machine don't experience this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Quick Look cache with `qlmanage -r`?

Comment: Just ran `qlmanage -r` and `qlmanage -r cache`. No effect. Restarted Finder. Same problem.